# Figuring out a File's File Extension after it's Changed

Tags: windows, file-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out the file type without an extension?](https://superuser.com/questions/435224/how-do-i-find-out-the-file-type-without-an-extension)

I am wondering if there is any way for understanding for example a file is a video file after we change it's file extension to something else like .bin ?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but if you load the file into a text/hex editor you can sometimes tell by the first couple bytes what the file type is...

Comment: Under unices you have the command `file` which looks at the magic bytes at the beginning of a file.  (You specified windows as OS, so this might not help you but it will help others who search for the same problem.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out the file type without an extension?](http://superuser.com/questions/435224/how-do-i-find-out-the-file-type-without-an-extension), [How to automatically recover lost file extensions?](http://superuser.com/questions/529435/how-to-automatically-recover-lost-file-extensions), [What utility or method can tell a file type accurately?](http://superuser.com/questions/62901/what-utility-or-method-can-tell-a-file-type-accurately) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this command line tool:

[Trid Tool](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html)

Very handy, there is a GUI version as well.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thnx